# Novel with resurrection of demonic master into young leader with weak body

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation

Looking for the novel, the main character was the leader of demon sect. He died (can’t remember how) and got reincarnated to the young master of some clan. Before death, young master loved to go the public house to have fun because he could do anything with his weak body. After reincarnation his body was weak and he decided to go to public house to get dirty energy from courtesans to heal his body. At the same time he hires doctor from demonic way to help him heal his body. Creates sub house in his sect with warriors as his own people.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any characters or places?

Comment: It was a year ago. And I do not actually remember where

Comment: I have found the novel. Thanks for the help. Cheonma wants to live quietly

Comment: Please post that as an answer so people can see the details.

Answer (score 1):

***[Cheonma Wants to Live Quietly](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/cheonma-wants-to-live-quietly-novel)*** aka *Heavenly Demon Wants to Live Quietly*.

> Cheonma’s story who wants to live peacefully and quietly in his newly acquired life.

Comment: Good job finding it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours have elapsed since the question was first posted.

Comment: Mentioning the demon part in the alternate title.